# image of convex closed, bounded subspace of H by monotonous continuous operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a Hilbert space and K a convex closed, bounded subspace of H.

Let $F : H → H$ be continuous monotonous function.

Prove that $F(K)$ is closed.

My argument is the following:

K is closed under H so K is a Hilbert space. F is continuous and monotonous so F(K) is a Hilbert subspace of H. I am not sure how to go from there.

Any hints or help?

Thank you.

Comment: What is a bounded subspace?

Comment: H is a Hilbert, so we have a norm $||.||_H$ using the scalar product. K is bounded for this norm, It means (I guess) $\forall k\in K, ||k||_H \le \alpha$ for some positive $\alpha$.

Comment: non-trivial (linear) subspaces are always unbounded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for $K$ being a subspace. Take $F$ to be linear, compact, and monotone. Let $K=H$. Compact operators do not have closed range.

It is true, if $K$ is assumed to be a convex, closed, bounded subset of $H$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $F(x_n)\to y$. It remains to show that there exists $x\in K$ with $F(x)=y$.

Since $K$ is weakly sequentially compact, we can assume (after possibly extracting a subsequence) that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ with $x\in K$.
Take some $v\in H$. By monotonicity, we have
$$
\langle F(x_n)-F(v),x_n-v\rangle\ge0.
$$
Passing to the limit shows
$$
\langle y-F(v),x-v\rangle\ge0\quad \forall v.
$$
Setting $v=x+ tw$ for some $w\in H$, $t>0$ gives
$$
\langle y-F(x+ tw),-t w\rangle\ge0
$$
Dividing by $t$, letting $t\searrow 0$ gives
$$
\langle y-F(x),-w\rangle\ge0\quad \forall w
$$
hence $y=F(x)$.

Comment: Thank you @daw! I have a question: Why is K weakly sequentially compact?